# sql union displays duplicates

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, union, having

image of what I want

[image]

I have tried the join on x or y and it didn't work, even the group by didn't work.
What almost gave me the result is the query below

```
SELECT A.Id ,A.AccNo ,A.Name ,B.Id ,B.AccNo1 ,B.AccNo2 ,B.Name 
   from Table1  as A 
   left outer  join Table2 as B on A.AccNo = B.AccNo1 
union 
 SELECT A.Id ,A.AccNo ,A.Name ,B.Id, B.AccNo1, B.AccNo2, B.Name, 
   from Table1 as A 
   left outer  join Table2 as B on A.AccNo = B.AccNo2
```

After getting the query correct I want to show only the exceptions where there was no link between the tables and its kind of difficult if the T1.ID is repeated

Comment: Dont post images.  Then post table structures is better than data exmaples

Comment: The posted SQL gives you a syntax error

Comment: It works but it gives duplicates which is what I don't want

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please explain what the logic is that builds up your required output

Comment: There are no duplicate _rows_ in your result!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id in (t2.accno1, t2.accno2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT A.Id ,A.AccNo ,A.Name ,B.Id ,B.AccNo1 ,B.AccNo2 ,B.Name 
from Table1  as A 
left outer  join Table2 as B 
ON A.AccNo = (CASE WHEN  A.AccNo = B.AccNo1 THEN B.AccNo1 ELSE B.AccNo2 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may nest your original query, and then use max aggregate function with grouping :

```
SELECT Id ,AccNo ,Name, max(Id2) as Id2, max(Name2) as Name2,
       max(AccNo1) as AccNo1, max(AccNo2) as AccNo2
  FROM
(
  SELECT A.Id ,A.AccNo ,A.Name ,B.Id Id2 ,B.AccNo1 ,B.AccNo2 ,B.Name Name2
     from Table1  as A 
     left outer  join Table2 as B on A.AccNo = B.AccNo1 
  union 
   SELECT A.Id ,A.AccNo ,A.Name ,B.Id Id2, B.AccNo1, B.AccNo2, B.Name Name2
     from Table1 as A 
     left outer  join Table2 as B on A.AccNo = B.AccNo2
) q  
GROUP BY Id ,AccNo ,Name;
```

[***`SQL Fiddle Demo`***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d0de/15)

Answer (score 0):

Do a `LEFT JOIN` to return the table1 values along with matching table2 values (where t2.accno2 = t1.accno):

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
     on t1.accno = t2.accno2
```

Or, perhaps you want table2 values for matching accno1's as well?

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
     on t1.accno in (t2.accno1, t2.accno2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It this way to resolve:

```
SELECT
 t1.id,
 t1.accno,
 t1.name,
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT
         id
     FROM
         table2
     WHERE
         accno2 = t1.accno
 ),
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT
         name
     FROM
         table2
     WHERE
         accno2 = t1.accno
 ),
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT
         accno1
     FROM
         table2
     WHERE
         accno2 = t1.accno
 ),
 (
     SELECT DISTINCT
         accno2
     FROM
         table2
     WHERE
         accno2 = t1.accno
 ) FROM
 table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.accno = t2.accno1 OR t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: select t1.id, 
    t1.accno, 
    t1.name, 
    (select distinct id from table2 where accno2=t1.accno), 
    (select distinct name from table2 where accno2=t1.accno),
    (select distinct accno1 from table2 where accno2=t1.accno),
    (select distinct accno2 from table2 where accno2=t1.accno)
from table1 t1  left  join
     table2 t2
     on t1.accno = t2.accno1 or t1.id=t2.id

Comment: I change code in answer - please marked as good answer. Thanx